# Animate specific dae objects based on condition

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

For 2 dae objects in the scene, how can one initiate animations for each one of them at different conditions?

Since all objects are part of the SCNScene, I am unable to refer to individual ones based on a condition. They all render properly, but they animate all the same time. Can we put a condition to make specific objects in the scene animate at a time?

Thanks in advance!

let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Avatar_1.dae")!

```
    // This node will be parent of all the animation models
    let node = SCNNode()

    // Add all the child nodes to the parent node
    for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {
        node.addChildNode(child)
    }

    // Set up some properties
    node.position = SCNVector3(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x+0.5,hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    node.scale = SCNVector3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    // Add the node to the scene
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

For another avatar (Avatar_2.dae), how do we add it in the scene but give another reference name.

Also how can we individually play/pause the animations for each avatars?

This one if for scene, but is there one for individual avatars?

sceneView.scene.isPaused = play

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly naming the elements in your SCNScene and then designating them as distinct nodes by using `rootNode.childNode(withName:)`:

```
   let scannerScene = SCNScene(named: "Scanner.scn")
   let sectorField: SCNNode = (scannerScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sectorField", recursively: true))! 
   let scanBeam: SCNNode = (scannerScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "scanBeam", recursively: true))!
```

Once you've done this, the individual nodes can be animated independently:

```
// start scanBeam
    let rotateAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(2*Float.pi), z: 0, duration: 1.5)
    let perpetualRotation = SCNAction.repeatForever(rotateAction)
    scanBeam.runAction(perpetualRotation)
```

To stop a specific animation (as opposed to all animations in the entire scene) simply remove the action

```
scanBeam.removeAction(forKey: String)
```